Lxd service not activated
following the installation of win11 VM on ubuntu system (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-a-windows-11-vm-using-lxd#3-create-a-new-vm)
lxc init win11 --vm --empty
this command gives
"Error: LXD unix socket "/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket" not accessible: permission denied"
i checked lxd system:
 snap services lxd
Service          Startup  Current   Notes
lxd.activate     enabled  inactive  -
lxd.daemon       enabled  inactive  socket-activated
lxd.user-daemon  enabled  inactive  socket-activated

does anyone could help plz??

Try snap start lxd. If that does not work, then please edit your question to show complete output.

it worked but main problem of lxc is still persistent lxc init win11 --vm --empty "Error: LXD unix socket "/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket" not accessible: permission denied"   how to proceed plz
